# Is “wierum” or “wieherum” an actual German word?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, colloquial

I’ve read a sentence which was one of the following:

> Wierum muss ich das halten?
>   Wieherum muss ich das halten?

However, the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/wieherum) and other dictionaries don’t have any entry for *wierum* or *wieherum.* I wonder whether they are actual words one can use?

Comment: It should be "wie rum" and "wie herum".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on a misunderstanding or typo.

Comment: rum and herum can be found in the Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rum http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herum

Comment: @Stephie That doesn’t make sense. It’s not a misunderstanding and probably not a typo. Whoever wrote it likely thought that _?wierum_ already was as conventionalized as similar _worum_. After all, there is no audible difference when spoken, i.e. you cannot hear whether it’s one word or two.

Comment: @Stephie: We usually consider questions based on typos and similar off-topic for the reasons that they are not of general interest and that we cannot answer much more than “It should be spelt *X.*”. In this case, however, both do not apply. I thus nominate this question for reopening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**wierum* is the concatenation of *wie rum*, which is the standard – not really colloquial any more – short form of *wie herum* ‘which way/orientation’. If it appears in a question, the answer will likely contain *so (he)rum*.

The writer probably wrote it as a single word because of the similar interrogative particles *worum* and *warum* or *wieso*, which all have the same counterpart *darum*. The *wo-/da-* pattern is very common in particular. 
Other compounds ending in *-rum* could have contributed as well, of course.

Maybe German orthography will develop that way and some day **wierum* and **sorum* will be listed in dictionaries, but for now the conventional spelling is with two words, although you could not infer that from its pronunciation.

Comment: I think "wierum" is simple a frequent spelling mistake of "wie rum" that doen't need to be justified, but corrected. "The writer probably wrote it as a single word because of the similar interrogative particles worum and warum or wieso [...]" I think, this is only speculartion.

Comment: @Iris My assertion is an informed, educated guess, hence “probably”. Since the spelling _wierum_ is motivated by following some orthographic rules, but not others (which is often an arbitrary convention anyhow), i.e. it can be justified, I would classify it as a **deviation**, not a **mistake**. Language, including orthography, evolves through deviations.

Comment: I would support your theory, if "worum" or "warum" were a combination of wo/wa + herum, but they aren't (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/worum). And "wieso" is written together, but "wie oft", "wie viel", and "wie lange" are seperated. So there is no pattern either.

Comment: They don’t have to be compositions of other existing word forms to serve as a conceptual model. (For instance, _da-_ is an allomorph of the article root in _der/die/das_, but is unrelated to existing _da_ ‘because’ or ‘there’.) Also, _wieviel_  and _wielange_ are often written as a single word, and so are _soviel_ and _solange_. I don’t think I’ve ever seen _wieoft_, but _sooft_ I’ve encountered more than once. Anyhow, your mentioning of other _-rum_ compounds is a sound explanation as well.

Comment: I am still not convinced of your theory, but obviously some people are. Btw, "wieviel" was written together before the [Rechtschreibreform 1996](Reform der deutschen Rechtschreibung von 1996), but nowadays only "wie viel" is correct. "wie lange" was always written in two words, when I remember correctly.

Answer (score 5):

> Wierum

is a very common spelling mistake. Maybe because other words with *herum*, or *rum* are written together, e.g. [*rechtsrum*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rechtsrum), *[rund­he­r­um](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rundherum)*, [*drumrum*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drumherum)  *[außenrum](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auszenrum)*

Correct is:

> "Wie rum ... " (coll.) or "Wie herum ..."